# Using a post-receive hook to create a zip

Tags: git, git-bash, git-post-receive

I've been playing around with hooks for a while now, but I can't seem to get the `post-receive` hook to work the way I need it to.

I am trying to get the `post-receive` hook to create a zip folder and place it somewhere outside the git repository folders after I have pushed my changes to the repository.

Comment: You should include the hook you've written in your question.

Answer (score 7):

You have a good example of deploying an zip through a post-receive hook in [this article](http://blog.danielbyrne.net/2012/02/a-quick-and-easy-way-to-deploy-from-git-with-post-commit-hooks/) from [Daniel Byrne](http://blog.danielbyrne.net/):

The idea is to use **[`git archive --format=zip`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive)**:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# A post commit hook that takes any updates pushed to the 'release' branch
# and creates a release directory for the new version under the webroot.
# Live site is then symlinked to this new release directory.

oldrev=$1
newrev=$2
branch=$3

# this is the root of the website (a symlink to a release directory)
webroot=/var/www/danielbyrne.net/www

if [ "$branch" == "release" ]
then

    # create a release directory to extract files into
    target=/var/www/danielbyrne.net/releases/$2/
    mkdir $target

    echo "Making target directory: $target"

    # create an archive in the webroot of danielbyrne.net
    /usr/bin/git archive master --format zip --output $target/deploy.zip

    echo "unzipping archive..."

    # extract the archive
    unzip -o -q $target/deploy.zip -d $target

    echo "removing deployment archive"

    # remove the archive file
    rm $target/deploy.zip

    echo "switching symbolic link to $target"

    # now switch the live site to point to the new release
    ln -nsf $target $webroot

    echo "done";
fi
```

Comment: I've tried using this but I keep getting the same error i had before which is 'warnign: could not find /tmp, please create' The problem is I've no idea how or where to create '/tmp'

Comment: @MikeyJ strange, because `/tmp`, as its own names indicates, should be there under `/` (root directory if the server). Maybe a access right issue.

Comment: Cool to see some of my code referenced on SO :-) @MikeyJ - are you using linux or cgywin on windows? Most distros will have a /tmp directory... at what point do you see the error, and where?

Comment: @managedheap84 yes, I liked your approach in this hook. Note that MikeJ has last been seen on Stack Overflow last February. You might not get an answer to your question right away ;)